# Prove that every element is a $p$-th power in a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime. show that in a cyclic group of order $p^n-1$, every element is a $p$-th power

My concern: I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but I think it should state that "every element is a $p^n$-th power," since I'm only able to show that for any element $g^k$ in cyclic group $G$ where $g$ is a generator, $(g^{k})^{p^{n}} = g^{k}.$

Comment: This is exercise 63 in chapter 4 in Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow G$ such that $x \mapsto x^p$.

Consider $x^p = e$.  Is this possible for $x \neq e$?  Of course not: if there were such an $x$, then its order is necessarily $p \implies p|(p^n-1)$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $\phi$ is injective, so it is an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Many thanks, Kaj! too slick:)

Answer (score 7):

Since $p$ does not divide $p^n-1$, it follows that $gcd(p,p^n-1)=1$. For all $x$ in a cyclic group of order $p^n-1$ one has $x^{p^n-1}=e$, by Lagrange's theorem. Now use Bézout's identity:

$$x=x^1=x^{kp+t(p^n-1)}=(x^k)^p$$

Comment: how do you know we have infinite k in order to get ALL $x^{k}$?

Comment: Bezout supplies you with as many $k$'s as you need.

Comment: Many thanks, Ittay! Great solution:)

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a concise one liner is simply letting $a$ be the generator, and then noting since $\gcd(p,p^n-1)=1$ (since $p$ is prime and does not divide $p^n-1$) that $|a^p|=(p^n-1)/{\gcd(p^n -1,p)}=p^n-1$, so $\langle a\rangle=\langle a^p \rangle$ and we're done.